# How to use devices field of the user table in FQL query?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I would like the result of a FQL query to only return friends of a user which have a iOS device in their devices list. The following query:

```
SELECT uid, first_name, devices 
FROM user 
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
ORDER BY profile_update_time DESC 
LIMIT 0, 100
```

returns a list like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "uid": 12345678, 
      "first_name": "John", 
      "devices": [
        {
          "os": "iOS", 
          "hardware": "iPhone"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "uid": 1234345678, 
      "first_name": "Pete", 
    }
}
```

Now I would like to only retrieve users who have at least one device where the os is "iOS". I have tried including

```
devices.os = "iOS"
```

in the query but this returned an error.

Is this possible through the FQL query?  Or should this be solved client side?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found out that it **IS** possible! You can use the `IN` operator just with the `devices` column. There is no need to restrict to os or hardware.

*Example: all friends that have an iPhone:* [try out](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20uid,%20name,%20devices%20FROM%20user%0AWHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29%0A%20%20AND%20%22iPhone%22%20IN%20devices%0AORDER%20BY%20profile_update_time%20DESC%20%0ALIMIT%200,%20100%0A%0A)

```
SELECT uid, name, devices FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
  AND "iPhone" IN devices
ORDER BY profile_update_time DESC 
LIMIT 0, 100
```

*Example: all friends that have an iOS device (e.g. iPhone or iPad):* [try out](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20uid,%20name,%20devices%20FROM%20user%0AWHERE%20uid%20IN%20%28SELECT%20uid2%20FROM%20friend%20WHERE%20uid1%20%3D%20me%28%29%29%0A%20%20AND%20%22iOS%22%20IN%20devices%0AORDER%20BY%20profile_update_time%20DESC%20%0ALIMIT%200,%20100%0A%0A)

```
SELECT uid, name, devices FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
  AND "iOS" IN devices
ORDER BY profile_update_time DESC 
LIMIT 0, 100
```

Hint: If you want to use this Query to build a custom Friend Picker to send invites to Facebook friends that not yet have installed your iOS app but have an iOS device, you want to include the following into your `WHERE` clause:

```
AND is_app_user = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not appear to be possible on the server side. The `devices` field is returned as an array, and FQL does not seem to have any methods that can search an array. As far as I can tell, the only way to explore this is on the client side.