# How is Facebook FQL devices array populated?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-android-sdk

I am testing invites with facebook for an Android app, so I want to invite all users that have an Android phone, for that this other question is very useful: [How to use devices field of the user table in FQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11684865/how-to-use-devices-field-of-the-user-table-in-fql-query)

The problem is trying to set up a test account.

- I have a facebook *test* account
- This account is friends with my normal facebook account
- I have signed in with facebook in a phone (Android, but not sure it matters)
- I have published a couple of status updates from the phone.

Still, this user is showing an empty "devices" field when I query for it (quering with the Graph explorer http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Any idea of how or when is this array populated / updated?

More details on this.

When posting from Facebook for Android, your post is displayed as from "Mobile" which *maybe* means that the app keys for Android and iOS are the same. Pity, that could have been a very easy way to differentiate them.

Then, since they can give you HW information *sometimes* (although I never saw it for Android) I thought it may be read from the User Agent of the browser when accessing the mobile web, so I tried it. Again, the devices field for this friends stays empty.

Things I've tried with no success on populating the devices field

- Log in on the Android app
- Liking an item from the Android app
- Posting a status update from the Android app
- Log in via the mobile web on an Android (Nexus One)
- Liking an item from the mobile web on an Android (Nexus One)
- Posting a status update from the mobile web on an Android (Nexus One)
- Log in in an Android game via Facebook SSO (just trying out of desperation)

Answer (score 0):

devices
array
An array of objects containing fields os, which may be a value of 'iOS' or 'Android', along with an additional field hardware which may be a value of 'iPad' or 'iPhone', if present. However, hardware may not be returned if we are unable to determine the exact hardware model and only the os

I have tested it on my own account, and my device is not defined, but i'am using ipad, 3 of my friends are on android, and 2 on IOS. So i think, that fb does not determine devices clearly

Comment: At the beginning I thought they were determining it properly but after going to some of my contacts asking, one of them uses iPad, iPhone and Android, being the iPad the most regularly used and only iPhone is shown for him.

Comment: it is because of using iphone fb apps on ipad

Comment: so is this "devices" field completely unreliable then?